# 'Missing }' with phonrule package

Tags: errors, linguistics

My first time messing around with the phonrule package, but I kept getting the same error in my larger, more complicated document to I recreated the diagram in this super-simple document - compiled with XeLaTeX - to make sure it wasn't something else causing it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{phonrule}
\begin{document}
\phonr{\oneof{m \\ n}}
      {m}
      {\oneof{\phold p \\ \phold b }}
\end{document}
```

But even just this gets me the error:

```
Missing } inserted.

<inserted text> 

   }

l.7 ... \\ n }}{m}{ \oneof{\phold p \\ \phold b }}
```

Definitely got something to do with the `\oneof` command, because removing that lets it compile normally.

It's probably something really small I'm missing, but I would really appreciate some help.

Or, if you can't help, are there any alternatives to getting the result I want, something like whats shown [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Linguistics#Phonological_rules)?

Comment: I get no error. What TeX distribution are you using? I can reproduce the error with TeX Live 2013.

Comment: Hi! I am the author of the package. As egreg, I get no error with MacTex 2015 and phonrule 1.2.0. Are you running the most updates versions of both TeX and phonrule?

Comment: TeXworks version 0.4.5. Not sure about phonrule's version.

Comment: TeXworks is just an editor. It doesn't compile the document. A TeX distribution would be something like TeX Live (inc. MacTeX) or MikTeX or whatever. Which distribution and which version are you using? Look in the `.log` file for details of the binary you are using to compile.